# App key and secret for connector in unificationengine

Tags: unificationengine

[image: App key screenshot]

What has to be given as values for "app key" and "app secret" if I need to add smtp connector for an app in Unificationengine? From where can I get those values?

Answer (score 0):

If the app does not have any key and secret, you can just give them as "no_key" and "no_secret".

Please check the following part of the documentation [image] in https://developer.unificationengine.com